Javascript forEach is not a function error when called on HTML element selection
The variable selectCol stores all select HTML elements.
const selectCol = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
selectCol.forEach(functionName());

But I cannot call a forEach function on this array, why?
I also tried the following:
selectCol[i].forEach(function());

I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: selectCol.forEach is not a function".

Right, getElementsByTagName returns a HTMLCollection, which doesn't contain the said method. Use querySelectorAll instead.
